# Earth is a good place?

Tags: translation

水善利萬物而不爭
處衆人之所惡
故幾於道。
**居善地**

Hello, it's from the eighth chapter of Dao De Jing.
I have translated it to:

```
the highest good is like water
the good virtue of water serves all, but without fighting
it takes place (所) that all people hate
**the best place (residence) - the earth (the lowest place)**
```

Can you correct me?

Zbigniew

Comment: Are you asking the meaning of 居善地?

Answer (score 1):

Your text is missing some punctuation.

上善若水。水善利万物而不争，处众人之所恶，故几于道。**居，善地**；心，善渊；与，善仁；言，善信；政，善治；事，善能；动，善时。夫唯不争，故无尤。

Translation of the explanation:

> The highest virtue is like water. Water benefits all while not competing, situating itself where others loath to go (low, wet areas), thus it is close to the ideal. One's home should be wisely located; one's emotions and thoughts should be calm and deep; toward others one should be kind and faithful; speech should be trustworthy; one should be diligent in performing the duties of a political office; when undertaking tasks one should make full use of assets and abilities; one should know how to seize an opportunity and take action. Only by not competing with others, can one avoid grudges.

Source: http://www.daodejing.org/8.html

> 第八章  [原文]
>
> 上善若水①。水善利万物而不争，处众人之所恶②，故几于道③。居，善地；心，善渊④；与，善仁⑤；言，善信；政，善治⑥；事，善能；动，善时⑦。夫唯不争，故无尤⑧。
>
> [译文]
>
> 最善的人好像水一样。水善于滋润万物而不与万物相争，停留在众人都不喜欢的地方，所以最接近于“道”。最善的人，居处最善于选择地方，心胸善于保持沉静而深不可测，待人善于真诚、友爱和无私，说话善于格守信用，为政善于精简处理，能把国家治理好，处事能够善于发挥所长，行动善于把握时机。最善的人所作所为正因为有不争的美德，所以没有过失，也就没有怨咎。
>
> [注释]
>
> ①上善若水：上，最的意思。上善即最善。这里老子以水的形象来说明"圣人"是道的体现者，因为圣人的言行有类于水，而水德是近于道的。
>
> ②处众人之所恶：即居处于众人所不愿去的地方。
>
> ③几于道：几，接近。即接近于道。
>
> ④渊：沉静、深沉。
>
> ⑤与，善仁：与，指与别人相交相接。善仁，指有修养之人。
>
> ⑥政，善治：为政善于治理国家，从而取得治绩。
>
> ⑦动，善时：行为动作善于把握有利的时机。
>
> ⑧尤：怨咎、过失、罪过。
>
> [引语]
>
> 在上一章以天地之道推及人道之后，这一章又以自然界的水来喻人、教人。老子首先用水性来比喻有高尚品德者的人格，认为他们的品格像水那样，一是柔，二是停留在卑下的地方，三是滋润万物而不与争。最完善的人格也应该具有这种心态与行为，不但做有利于众人的事情而不与争，而且还愿意去众人不愿去的卑下的地方，愿意做别人不愿做的事情。他可以忍辱负重，任劳任怨，能尽其所能地贡献自己的力量去帮助别人，而不会与别人争功争名争利，这就是老子“善利万物而不争”的著名思想。
>
> [评析]
>
> 老子在自然界万事万物中最赞美水，认为水德是近于道的。而理想中的"圣人"是道的体现者，因为他的言行有类于水。为什么说水德近于道呢？王夫之解释说："五行之体，水为最微。善居道者，为其微，不为其著；处众之后，而常德众之先。"以不争争，以无私私，这就是水的最显著特性。水滋润万物而无取于万物，而且甘心停留在最低洼、最潮湿的地方。在此后的七个并列排比句中，都具有关水德的写状，同时也是介绍善之人所应具备的品格。老子并列举出七个"善"字，都是受到水的启发。最后的结论是：为人处世的要旨，即为"不争"。也就是说，宁处别人之所恶也不去与人争利，所以别人也没有什么怨尤。
>
> 《荀子·宥坐》记载了孔子答第子子贡问水的一段对话："孔子观于东流之水。子贡问于孔子曰：君子之所以见大水必观焉者，是何？孔子曰：夫水，偏与诸生而无为也，似德。其流也埤下，裾拘必循其理，似义。其洮洮乎不屈尽，似道。若有决行之，其应佚若声响，其赴而仞之谷不惧，似勇。主量必平，似法，盈不求概，似正。淖约微达，似察。以出以入，以就鲜洁，似善化。其万折也必东，似志。是故君子见大水必观焉。"在此处，孔子以水描述了他理想中的具备崇高人格的君子形象，这里涉及到德、义、道、勇、法、正、察、志以及善化等道德范畴。这其中的观点与道家有显而易见的区别，但也有某些相似之处。可以此段引文与《道德经》第八章参照阅读。

Answer (score 1):

居善地，心善淵，與善仁，言善信，正善治，事善能，動善時。

河上公注：

- 居善地： 水性善喜於地，草木之上，即流而下，有似於牝動而下人也。
- 心善淵： 水深空虛，淵深清明。
- 與善仁： 萬物得水以生，與虛不與盈也。
- 言善信： 水內影照形，不失其情也。
- 正善治： 無有不洗，清且平也。
- 事善能： 能方能圓，曲直隨形。
- 動善時： 夏散冬凝，應期而動，不失天時。

I prefer the explanation given by "河上公".  "居善地" is to nourish the place it stays/lives.